# Want to extract day number and day time from current data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am reading cloudfront logs using logstash and storing the data into elasticsearch, the process works fines and stores all the required fields, so far I have 11M records in cluster. Now for the statistics purposes I feel it would have been better and easy if I had stored day name, day number and time of the day from the very beginning. Can I now update the current data and have these fields ?

Comment: You are trying to have these new fields on your old data or future records?

Comment: old dat as well as future records @SathishkumarRakkiasamy

Answer (score 1):

For future data you would implement a logstash filter with the required logic. For your past data you will have to reindex them.

Comment: future data is the easy part, the problem is updating past data

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you will have to reindex them since updating the 11M documents by hand would be a huge effort (and not automated) in my opinion.

Comment: can I use copy_to parameter ?

Comment: Where and on what would you want to apply this parameter?

Comment: I see it now, I can use reindex API and in the new index I can define my mapping which takes the timestamp and then extracts the date/day/hour from it and stores it into respective columns

Comment: You got it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can add new fields to the existing index. For more details, you can refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html)

Adding new fields to the old index won't reflect in query search with mapping. Better create a new index with all the fields, settings and mapping or reindex the old and new data in the same index(costly process).

Elasticsearch allows you to create a copy(clone) of the index. Using this gradually you can update the copied index with a new approach(adding new fields). Once this index is up then you can make copied index as your primary index. It needs some effort. Please do refer this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) for clone.

Comment: ok thank you for your help I will try to implement it and then chose an answer accepted